# 100% width header fixed with two div's

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a fixed header that sticks to the top on scroll. I have one wrapper (#topbarwrapper) that should fit 100% across the entire browser. I also have another div wrapper (.topbarcontentWRAPPER ) inside the(#topbarwrapper)  which includes logo and navigation (#mainNav). One floats to the left and the other floats to the right. They both float as they should but it seems as if when the browser is resized, the divs move. I want the two divs floating inside to be centered with the entire page. The layout is responsive so the body width is 90%. I spent several days trying to figure this out including research. Any help would be appreciated.

Ideal goal is to have the header with 100% width fixed and centered.

Layout View: 
http://s30.postimg.org/so036qarl/Screen_shot_2014_03_10_at_1_53_42_AM.jpg

HTML:

```
     <body>

        <div id="topbarWRAPPER">
                           <div class="topbarcontentWRAPPER">
              <a href="http://link" title="fvfg" id="topbarLOGO"></a>
              <nav id="mainNav" role="navigation">
                <h2 class="hidden">Main Site Navigation</h2>
                 <?php if ($this->countModules('nav')): ?>
                 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="nav"   />
                 <?php endif; ?> 
              </nav>
           </div>
   </div>     
        <div id="mobilelogo"></div>



          <div id="imageshow">


      </div>


       <div class="wrap">


           <div class="miscellaneousRow">

              </div>


              <div class="search">

              </div>

           </div> 

           <section><h2 class="hidden">Recent News</h2>
           <article id="recentNews">
              <jdoc:include type="component" />
           </article>
           </section>


           <aside>
               <div class="sideBOX">    <section>  
                 <h1 class="sideHeader">MAILING LIST</h1>

                 <div class="signup">

              </section>   </div>


            <div class="sideBOX">   <section>



            </section></div>


         <div class="tabviewTABS">    <section> 


           </section>
               </div>      </aside>
```

```
        <footer id="mainbottomFooter">
           <div class="footerFLOATLEFT">
            <h1 class="hidden">Footer</h1>
              <div class="floatone">

              </div>
           </div>

        </footer>
          <div class="secondbottomFooter"> <div class="secondbottomfooterRight">


                  <nav id="sidenav">


                    <ul>

                       <li>

                        <a href="http://www.link.com" target="_blank">l</a>
                       </li>

                       <li>        


                          <a href="http://www.link.com" target="_blank">f</a>
                       </li>

                       <li>

                          <a href="https://link.com" target="_blank">g</a>
                       </li>

                       <li>

                          <a href="http://link.com" target="_blank">x</a>
                       </li>

                       <li>

                          <a href="about.asp">!</a>
                       </li>
                    </ul>
                 </nav>  
              </div>
            <div class="secondbottomfooterLeft"> content</a></div>

           </div>
  </html>
```

```
body {
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-width:1024px;
    max-width:1580px;

    }


 .latest-post clearfix{
    display:hidden;}

.imageshow {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;


}

 .blog-readmore{
    font-size: 24px;
    display: inline;
    width: 180px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin-top:20px;


}



.blog-readmore a:link{
    font-family: arial;

    color: #690000;

    }
.blog-readmore a:visited{
        color: #690000;

}

.blog-readmore a:hover{
        color: #eee;

}



#topbarWRAPPER{
    position:fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color:#000;
    z-index:1000;
    text-align:center;

}

.topbarcontentWRAPPER {
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}





     #topbarLOGO
{

    background-image:url("http://strip2.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
   display:block;      
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width:250px;
      text-indent:-9999px;
}


aside{
        background-color: #d6d6d6;
    width: 29.1%;
padding-left:1%;

height: 100%;
    float: right;
    overflow: none;
        color: #fff;
                        font-size:10px;
                padding-bottom:1000em;
margin-bottom:-1000em
} 




         /* Blog content */



#recentNews {
    width: 65.1%;
    float: left;
    padding-right:2%;
    padding-left:2%;
    padding-bottom:2%;
background-color:#fff;
padding-bottom:1000em;
margin-bottom:-1000em;
    }


.wrap{ overflow:hidden;
background-color:#fff;
}

/* ~~ Bottom footer ~~ */
#mainbottomFooter{

    background-color:#000;
    position:relative;
    height: 300px;
        clear: both;
        padding:15px 0;
        min-width:100%;

    }


.footerFLOATLEFT li{
     list-style-type: none;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
        padding-top: 1em;
     }




.footerFLOATLEFT a:link{
    font-size:12px;
    color: #555555;
    text-transform:uppercase;}


.footerFLOATLEFT a:visited {
font-size:12px;
    color: #555555;
    text-transform:uppercase;}

    .footerFLOATLEFT a:hover {
font-size:12px;
    color: #690000;
    text-transform:uppercase;}


     /* ~~ P~~ */

p{
            font-size: 17px;
        color: #000; 
        line-height:140%;
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue';
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right:1%;
    font-weight:bold;


     }

h3 {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
font-size: 2em;
color: #690000;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-weight:300;
text-transform:uppercase;
padding-bottom:1em;
padding-top:1em;


}




.floatone {
    float:left;
        padding-right: 4em;
            padding-top: 4em;
            height: 100%;}


.floattwo {

    float:left;
    height: 100%;
        padding: 4em;}


.floatthree {
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
        padding: 4em;}


.floatfour {
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
        padding: 4em;}


.signup {
        width:100%;}





.footerFLOATLEFT {
width:100%;
float:left;

  }


.secondbottomFooter {
    width: 100%;
    height:40px;
background-color:#690000;
border-top:1px solid #222;
border-bottom:1px solid #222;
color: #fff;
font-size: 12px;

padding-top:2em;
padding-bottom:2em;
text-align:right;
  }


h2 {font-face:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 1em;
        padding-bottom: 1em;}


#sidenav {


    }


#sidenav li {
display:inline;

}




#sidenav a:link{
    font-family: 'socialicoregular', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:5em;
    color: #eee;
    text-decoration:none;

    }
#sidenav a:visited{
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration:none;
}

#sidenav a:hover{
        color: #690000;
        text-decoration:none;
}

.miscellaneousRow {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
        position:relative;
}

        .twitterFeed {float:left;
            padding-top: 10px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
                width: 65.1%;
                                }

            .search {
                float: right;
                padding:2%;
                width: 26%;}






#mainNav {
float:right;
}

.sideDivider {
    background-color:#222;
    height:auto;
    margin-bottom:10%;
    padding-top:10%;
    padding-bottom:5%;
    padding-left:5%;
    padding-right:5%;
    }



.tabviewTABS {
    background-color:#222;
    height:auto;
    margin-bottom:20%;
    padding-top:10%;
    padding-bottom:5%;
    padding-left:5%;
    padding-right:5%;
    }


.sideBOX {
    background-color:#222;
    height:auto;
    margin-bottom:10%;
    padding-top:10%;
    padding-bottom:5%;
    padding-left:5%;
    padding-right:5%;
    text-align:center;
    }



.soundcloud {
    background-color:#222;
position:relative;
    height:auto;
        clear: both;
        padding:15px 0;
        min-width:100%;



    }


.soundcloudtitle {
font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 2em;
        text-align:right;
        text-transform: uppercase;
                margin-bottom: 1em;
            border-bottom: 5px solid #690000;


    }

.secondbottomfooterRight p{

    padding-right:3em;
    padding-bottom:1em;
    }

.hidden 
    {
  position: absolute !important;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the left and right positions of your `topbarWRAPPER` to 0px instead of 5%.

See [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mGjC3/).

**EDIT:**
I see what you mean. I've updated [**the fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mGjC3/2/). It should be what you need.

**EDIT #2:**
Alrighty. Forgive me, I didn't notice this earlier. You've assigned the body a width in percent but a min and max width in pixels. If you remove the min and max widths you'll see the behavior you're looking for, but what I *think* you should do is assign the 70% width to `.wrap` and give it a `margin:0 auto;`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. The reason for me having left and right at 0px is to extend the topbarWRAPPER outside of the main webpage body and 100% across the screen so that the entire div stick to the top of the page.  I could be explaining it wrong but to give a better example of what I'm trying to do, here is the link the a template that does exactly how I want it.   [link](http://demo.gavick.com/joomla25/game/)

Comment: I really appreciate the fact that you are helping me with. It's still not working. The content in the TOPBARCONTENTWRAPPER is still extending beyonf the centered page content. I created a {link](http://jsfiddle.net/CQLnS/).  You can also see how the content keep extending. It does this for the logo and nav.  [link] (http://postimg.org/image/undweouq9/).

Comment: Thank you that worked! The wrap is just to give both colums equal height using padding-bottom:1000em;
margin-bottom:-1000em  and putting overflow:none; on the .wrap

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but i have one last question, that fixed the extending issue, do you have any suggest to keep the logo and nav from underlapping? It seems as if when the browser gets small the nav goes underneath the logo. i would like for both of them to stay where they are.. Here is a fiddle  [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/CQLnS/1/)

Comment: This is where min-width comes in handy. You'll need to put `min-width:500px` on both the body and the topbarcontentWRAPPER. 500px in this case because that's the total width of the nav and logo combined.